# Use JavaScript to intercept all document link clicks

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, cross-browser

How do I intercept link clicks in document?
It must be cross-platform.

I am looking for something like this:

```
// content is a div with innerHTML
var content = document.getElementById("ControlPanelContent");

content.addEventListener("click", ContentClick, false);

 function ContentClick(event) {
 
    if(event.href == "http://oldurl")
  {
     event.href = "http://newurl";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
for (var ls = document.links, numLinks = ls.length, i=0; i<numLinks; i++){
    ls[i].href= "...torture puppies here...";
}
```

alternatively if you just want to intercept, not change, add an onclick handler. This will get called before navigating to the url:

```
var handler = function(){
    ...torment kittens here...
}
for (var ls = document.links, numLinks = ls.length, i=0; i<numLinks; i++){
    ls[i].onclick= handler;
}
```

Note that `document.links` also contains `AREA` elements with a `href` attribute - not just `A` elements.

Answer (score 58):

What about the case where the links are being generated while the page is being used? This occurs frequently with today's more complex front end frameworks.

The proper solution would probably be to put the click event listener on the document. This is because events on elements propagate to their parents and because a link is actually acted upon by the top-most parent.

This will work for all links, whether they are loaded with the page, or generated dynamically on the front end at any point in time.

```
function interceptClickEvent(e) {
    var href;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName === 'A') {
        href = target.getAttribute('href');

        //put your logic here...
        if (true) {

           //tell the browser not to respond to the link click
           e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}


//listen for link click events at the document level
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('click', interceptClickEvent);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent('onclick', interceptClickEvent);
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer as it creates less event handlers and covers cases where links are generated dynamically, e.g. in a CMS like we are working on.

Comment: Note that `<a>` can be wrapped around other elements, in which case the event target is not actually `A`. Also note that this won't work if the user uses `<TAB>` to focus the link, and then presses `<ENTER>`. If you want to intercept everything that changes the page, you would need to replace all of the a-tags and form-tags, and detect dynamic elements with MutationObserver.

Comment: For nested elements such as a `<span>` inside of an `<a>` you can use `.closest()`: `if (target.tagName !== 'a') target = target.closest('a');`.

Answer (score 4):

I just found this out and it may help some people. In addition to interception, if you want to disallow the link to load another page or reload the current page. Just set the href to '#' (as in internal page ref prefix). Now you can use the link to call a function while staying at the same page.

Comment: Update: This is not the best way. Using `href="javascript:void(0)"` is often better since it doesn't force the page to reload. [more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Comment: Note that both of these ways prevent users from using Right Click actions on the links (open in new tab, etc.)