# change url links on document load

Tags: javascript, url, coding-style, hyperlink, bookmarklet

i have this js bookmarklet that makes all the current page's font colors black.
what i wanted is to maintein the effect of the bookmarklet even clicking on the page's links

```
javascript:(
function(){ 
 var newSS, styles='* { color: black !important }';
 if(document.createStyleSheet) { 
  document.createStyleSheet("javascript:'"+styles+"'"); 
 } else { 
  newSS=document.createElement('link'); 
  newSS.rel='stylesheet'; 
  newSS.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles); 
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS); 
 }
}
)();
```

so i though if there is a way we can change the current page's links into something like

*<a href="javascript:'load link location' then 'apply color effect'">Link</a>*

*cant actually think of the right codes lol
i don't want to use stylish addons or something like that xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of parts to this:

1. Write some javascript to intercept all link clicks and redirect to your function.  See [Use Javascript to Intercept All Document Link Clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136461/use-javascript-to-intercept-all-document-link-clicks).
2. Write the function that gets called on link intercept.  This function would do the following:

   1. Pull the href of the link and place it in `document.location`.
   2. Call your black highlight function

So roughly the code would look something like this:

```
functionToHighlightTextBlack();  // Apply to current page

// Apply to future page
for (var ls = document.links, numLinks = ls.length, i=0; i < numLinks; i++){
    ls[i].onClick = function() {
       document.location = ls[i].href;
       functionToHighlightTextBlack();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to put this code javascript:for(var ls=document.links,ln= ls.length, i=0;i<ln;i++){ls[i].href="javascript:alert('hi');";} after putting it in the address bar it only shows the word javascript:alert('hi');

Comment: @kapitanluffy - You missed the setup code; try this: `javascript:(function(){ for(var ls=document.links,ln= ls.length, i=0;i<ln;i++){ls[i].href="javascript:alert('hi');";}})();`